# How to keep a process alive after remote PowerShell script completion?

Tags: c#, powershell, solr, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to start Zookeeper and Solr remotely via PowerShell scriptblock. 
Then I see that the process is created in the remote machine (by checking the port 2181 of Zookeeper). And on the script completion it is being terminated. 
How do I keep this alive even after the completion?

This code below stops the remote process on script completion. The `script.ps1` does a lot of things that includes starting Zookeeper and Solr asJob.

```cs
int iRemotePort = 5985;
string strShellURI = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
string strAppName = @"/wsman";
WSManConnectionInfo ci = new WSManConnectionInfo(
    false,
    machineName,
    iRemotePort,
    strAppName,
    strShellURI,
    new PSCredential(userName, secure));

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ci);
runspace.Open();
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    session.Log(@"c:\temp\script.ps1 -serverID " + counter + " -copySolrConfig $" + status + " -currentHost \"" + machineName + "\" -IP_PORT_List \"" + String.Join(", ", machineWithPort) + "\"");
    ps.Runspace = runspace;
    ps.AddScript(@"c:\temp\script.ps1 -serverID " + counter + " -copySolrConfig $" + status + " -currentHost \"" + machineName + "\" -IP_PORT_List \"" + String.Join(", ", machineWithPort) + "\"");

    var results = ps.Invoke();

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        session.Log(result.ToString());
    }
}
runspace.Close();
```

Comment: For help with your code: show your code.

Answer (score 0):

So after a long try I came to a conclusion, Using power-shell script alive  is not a appropriate way to keep zookeeper and solr running effectively. So moved it as a windows service and installed it on the remote machine via WiX.